# JqGrid Checkbox Field Implementation Fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Using JqGrid, I'm simply trying to implement a checkbox field which updates database data with an ajax request each time the user checks / unchecked. This is my failed attempt:

```
{name:'fastpass',index:'fastpass',width:20,editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions:{
value:"True:False",
dataEvents:[{
type:'click',fn:function(e){
alert();
}
}]
}, formatter:"checkbox", formatoptions:{disabled:false} }
```

But I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong to not get the alert(). What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            { name: 'fastpass',
                index: 'fastpass',
                width: 20,
                editable: true,
                edittype: 'checkbox', 
                editoptions: {
                    value: "True:False",
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'click', fn: function (e) {
                            alert();
                        }
                    }],
                    formatter: "checkbox", 
                },
                formatoptions: { disabled: false }
            }
```

Comment: Isn't it essentially the same thing?